# Use of unresolved operator <=

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, swift3

I am trying to use Swift 3 for-loops, but I have been unsuccessful. Here is what I have:

```
for assumedPayRate: Double in (0.25..<=billRate) where assumedPayRate += 0.25 {
```

On the `..<=` it gives me the error:

> Use of unresolved operator '..<='

Here is the original Swift 2 version:

```
for var assumedPayRate:Double = 0.25; assumedPayRate <= billRate; assumedPayRate += 0.25 {
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator `..<=` doesn't exist in Swift and your syntax is invalid. Use `stride` instead:

```
// Assuming billRate is a Double
for assumedPayRate in stride(from: 0.25, through: billRate, by: 0.25) {
    // Do your things
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift has two range operators - `...` and `..<`.

The `...` operator corresponds to

```
for i = start ; i <= end ; i++
```

while `..<` corresponds to

```
for i = start ; i < end ; i++
```

in pseudocode.

You can use `...` operator for ¼ step (i.e. `0.25`):

```
for r in 1 ..< 4*billRate {
    let assumedPayRate = r / 4.0
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no ..<=, you need to convert your statement to while

```
var assumedPayRate = 0.25
while assumedPayRate <= billRate {
   ... // processing

   assumedPayRate += 0.25
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `advanced operator` to do the job, but you need to write it your own. The [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html) may help.